# Function not being called when it should be in node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, caesar-cipher

I am trying to call the `reverseEncryption` function whenever a negative number is passed into the the prompt in node. Unfortunately, the `console.log` is displayed but the `reverseEncryption` does not. For example if I encrypt `hello` with a key of `2` the result is `uqiim`. If if then go through the app again but decrypt `uqiim` with a key of `-2` I want the `reverseEncryption` function called and producing `hello`.

```
//Caesar cipher in node
var inquirer = require("inquirer");

inquirer.prompt([
  {
    type: "input",
    name: "message",
    message: "Write the message you would like to encrypt:"
  },
  {
    type: "input",
    name: "key",
    message: "Enter a number between 0 and 25"
  }
]).then(function(encrypted) {

  var newMessage = '';

  if (encrypted.key < 0) {
    console.log("cypher key is negative");
    reverseEncryption();
  } else {
    console.log("cypher key is " + encrypted.key)

    for (var i = 0; i < encrypted.message.length; i++) {
      var newKey = encrypted.message[i];

      //if (newKey.match(/[a-z]/i)){
      var newCode = encrypted.message.charCodeAt(i);

      if ((newCode >= 65) && (newCode <= 90)) {
        newKey = String.fromCharCode(((newCode - 65 + encrypted.key) % 26) + 65);
      } else if ((newCode >= 97) && (newCode <= 122)) {
        newKey = String.fromCharCode(((newCode - 97 + encrypted.key) % 26) + 97);
      }
      //}
      newMessage += newKey;
    }
  }
  console.log(newMessage);
});



var reverseEncryption = function() {
  var reverseMessage = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < encrypted.message.length; i++) {
    var reverseKey = encrypted.message[i];

    //if (newKey.match(/[a-z]/i)){
    var reverseCode = encrypted.message.charCodeAt(i);

    if ((reverseCode >= 65) && (reverseCode <= 90)) {
      reverseKey = String.fromCharCode(((reverseCode - 65 + (encrypted.key + 26)) % 26) + 65);
    } else if ((reverseCode >= 97) && (reverseCode <= 122)) {
      reverseKey = String.fromCharCode(((reverseCode - 97 + (encrypted.key + 26)) % 26) + 97);
    }
    reverseMessage += reverseKey;
  }
  console.log(reverseMessage);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you don't pass `encrypted` to your function that you store in `reverseEncryption`. Within that function the `encrypted`, and because of that your script will fail.

When using Promises you should always use a `catch` at the end of you chain to check if there was an error or not.

```
inquirer.prompt([
  {
    type: "input",
    name: "message",
    message: "Write the message you would like to encrypt:"
  },
  {
    type: "input",
    name: "key",
    message: "Enter a number between 0 and 25"
  }
]).then(function(encrypted) {
   // the res of you code
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

This `.catch` callback would have reported: `[ReferenceError: encrypted is not defined]`

To solve this you should call the unction using `reverseEncryption(encrypted);`  and the function itself needs to have a parameter `function (encrypted) { }`